# Hyperref linking to first page when using \captionlistentry

Tags: hyperref, captions, links

On my document, I have defined a new `trivfloat` environment in order to make a *list of equations*. To add elements to this list I use `\captionlistentry` (in order to avoid the caption appearing under the equation). However, I've realized that when using [`hyperref`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref), all links appearing in the *list of equations* link to the first page. I've looked in `hyperref`'s documentation and over the Internet but couldn't find anything that help me solve this problem.

Here's a minimal example of what I've done:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{trivfloat}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\trivfloat{Equation}

\begin{document}

\listof{Equation}{List of Equations}

\chapter*{}
\begin{Equation}[!htb]
\begin{equation}
6 \times 9 = 42
\end{equation}
\captionlistentry{Life, the universe and everything}
\end{Equation}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT:**

I've manage to find a solution to the minimal example thanks to the answer of John Kormylo:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{trivfloat}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{environ}

\trivfloat{Equation}

\newsavebox{\tempbox}

\begin{document}

\let\oldEquation=\Equation
\let\oldendEquation=\endEquation
\let\Equation\relax
\let\endEquation\relax
\NewEnviron{Equation}[1][hbtp]%
{\oldEquation[#1]%
 \savebox{\tempbox}{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%
   \BODY
   \end{minipage}}%
 \hypertarget{Equation.\thechapter.\theequation}{\usebox{\tempbox}}%
 \oldendEquation}

\listof{Equation}{List of Equations}

\chapter*{}
\begin{Equation}[!htb]
\begin{equation}
6 \times 9 = 42
\end{equation}
\captionlistentry{Life, the universe and everything}
\end{Equation}

\end{document}
```

However, this solution doesn't work if the Equation is inside a `\chapter` (instead of being inside `\chapter*`). Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Linking to the first page is the default when \hyperlink can't find the target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hyperref modifies `\caption` to add the `\hypertarget`, but it does not modify `\captionlistentry`.  To link to the equation (as opposed to beneath it) one needs to put the entire equation environment inside the `\hypertarget`, which is before the equation counter is incremented.

Interestingly, the Equation environment is not defined until `\begin{document}`.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{trivfloat}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{environ}

\trivfloat{Equation}

\newsavebox{\tempbox}

\begin{document}

\let\oldEquation=\Equation
\let\oldendEquation=\endEquation

\makeatletter
\RenewEnviron{Equation}[1][hbtp]%
{\oldEquation[#1]%
 \savebox{\tempbox}{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%
   \BODY
   \end{minipage}}%
 \hypertarget{\@currentHref}{\usebox{\tempbox}}%
 \oldendEquation}
\makeatother

\listof{Equation}{List of Equations}

\chapter*{}
\begin{Equation}[!htb]
\begin{equation}
6 \times 9 = 42
\end{equation}
\captionlistentry{Life, the universe and everything}
\end{Equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, your implementation gives me an error with the use of \RenewEnviron. I've manage to solve this error using \NewEnviron instead. The problem now is that although this solution works for the minimal example, it doesn't work if the Equation is inside a \chapter. I'm going to update the post with the new information.

Comment: Sorry about that.  Long story short, hyperref uses \@currentHref for the hypertarget, so this should always work.  BTW, you might try updating your packages.

Comment: This works great, thank you. The only detail is that \RenewEnviron is still giving me issues, but I've managed to solve them by using \NewEnviron (as in my previous example).

Answer (score 1):

A simpler alternative to John Kormylo's solution:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{hypcap}

\begin{document}

\begin{<float env>}
  \capstart
  \captionlistentry{<list entry>}
  ...
\end{<float env>}
```

To keep it DRY, we can define a new environment:

```
\newenvironment{listfloat}[1]
{
  \begin{<float env>}
    \capstart
    \captionlistentry{#1}
}{
  \end{<float env>}
}
```

In my case, I am using this to be able to hyperlink to pseudocode procedures that follow the syntax used in [*Introduction to Algorithms*](https://mitpress.mit.edu/9780262046305/introduction-to-algorithms/). Here is the code I use:

```
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{hypcap}
\usepackage[plain]{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\newcommand{\Title}[2]{\item[$\Call{#1}{#2}$]}

\renewcommand{\listalgorithmname}{List of Procedures}

% Usage:
%   \begin{procedure}{position}{title}{args}
%   ...
%   \end{procedure}
\newenvironment{procedure}[3]
{
  \begin{algorithm}[#1]
  \capstart
  \captionlistentry{\Call{#2}{}}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \Title{#2}{#3}
}{
  \end{algorithmic}
  \end{algorithm}
}

\begin{document}
```

Example usage:

```
% Same preamble as above

\newcommand{\floor}[1]{\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor}

\begin{document}
\begin{procedure}{!ht}{Merge-Sort}{A, p, r}
\If{$p \geq r$}
    \State \Return
\EndIf
\State $q = \floor{(p + r) / 2}$
\State $\Call{Merge-Sort}{A, p, q}$
\State $\Call{Merge-Sort}{A, q + 1, r}$
\State $\Call{Merge}{A, p, q, r}$
\end{procedure}
\end{document}
```

Which produces the following output:
[image]
[image]